# How to create a polymorphic numeric value from a String

Tags: scala

I'd like to be able to generate values of X, where X <: Numeric[X], from a String. The particular type of X should be inferred from the context.

Here's some similar code that works as expected:

```
def unity[X : Numeric]: X = implicitly[Numeric[X]].one
val x = unity[Int]
```

This results in x being an Int with value 1.

Now, what I really want to do is to implement the following method:

```
def valueOf[X : Numeric](s: String): X = ???
```

Any suggestions? (Probably, Try[X] would be a better return type but let's not worry about that for now).

Comment: Maybe instead of `Numeric`, create another typeclass for objects that can be parsed from string and implement it for types you want to use it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much, Łukasz. This is so obvious, yet I hadn't thought of it. Here's what I put together (very simplistic):

```
trait Valuable[X] {
  def plus(x: X, y: X): X
  def times(x: X, y: X): X
  def minus(x: X, y: X): X
  def fromString(x: String): X
}
object Valuable {
  implicit object ValuableDouble extends Valuable[Double] {
    def plus(x: Double, y: Double): Double = x + y
    def times(x: Double, y: Double): Double = x * y
    def minus(x: Double, y: Double): Double = x - y
    def fromString(x: String): Double = x.toDouble
  }
  implicit object ValuableInt extends Valuable[Int] {
    def plus(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
    def times(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x * y
    def minus(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x - y
    def fromString(x: String): Int = x.toInt
  }
}
```

Probably, what I really should do is to extend *Numeric*, or *Fractional* just to add in the *fromString* method.

My parser combinator now has code that looks something like this (much simplified here):

```
import Valuable._
trait MyValue {
  def asValuable[X : Valuable]: X
}
case class MyExpression(s: String) extends MyValue {
  override def asValuable[X: Valuable]: X = implicitly[Valuable[X]].fromString(s)
}
```

And I can test it thus:

```
"1" should "produce 1 for Int and 1.0 for Double" in {
  val x = MyExpression("1")
  x.asValuable[Int] shouldBe 1
  x.asValuable[Double] shouldBe 1.0
}
```

Everything works as expected.